# "Line integrals" vs "integration on manifolds" in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-analysis, differential-forms

I'm getting very muddled by the notion(s) of integration used in Lee's book. At first I thought the 4th chapter on the integral of 1-forms was separated from the main treatment of integration in chapter 10 simply because the author wished to present an application early on in the text to stop things getting too terse, but after closely looking at the two definitions I'm starting to get paranoid that these integrals are subtly different.

In chapter 4 our integral requires a curve $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow M$ and a $1$-form to be integrated $\omega$ that eats vectors from $T_{\gamma(t)}[a,b]$. Our "abstract manifold" is really just the interval $[a,b]$. What confuses me is we have this freedom to choose the manifold $M$ which $\gamma$ maps into.

We define $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \omega:=\int_a^b\gamma^*\omega$

Compare this to chapter 10 where we are integrating in an $n$ manifold $N$, and we integrate the $n$-form $\omega \in T^* N$ by taking the pullback of an inverse chart map $\varphi^{-1}$.

Here we have $\displaystyle \int_U \omega:=\int_{\varphi(U)}{(\varphi^{-1})}^*\omega$

At first glance it looks obvious, the curve is just like the inverse chart map for a 1-D manifold, job is done. However, if I want to do the "chapter 10 integrals" in 1-D then $N = [a,b]$ my chart maps $\varphi : U\subset N \rightarrow \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}$, in particular, note how since $N$ is a 1-d manifold, my chart can only map to subsets of the real line by definition of being a smooth manifold of dimension 1. There is no freedom like in chapter 4 to get exotic curves in $\mathbb{R}^2, \mathbb{R}^3$ or any $M$.

What's going on here? Is there some freedoms that you can get in 1-D that don't exist in higher dimensions? I certainly remember my vector calculus courses letting me do line integrals in any number of dimensions I wanted, Lee's example 4.18 certainly shows a nice curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$, while the chapter 10.22 example has a 2-form integrated on sphere which is calculated by pulling back with a map $F:D \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$, like we are trapped in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the same dimension as the manifold!

Even the name line integral begins to confuse me, are integrals of differential forms meant to generalise integrals from calculus such as

$\hspace{15mm}\displaystyle \int {\bf{v}} \cdot d{\bf{r}} \hspace{10mm}\text{or}\hspace{10mm} \int f({\bf{r}})ds \hspace{10mm}\text{or}\hspace{10mm} \int f(x)dV$?

Chapter 4 makes it sound like differential forms give us $n$-dimensional analogues on curved spaces to integrals like the left, while chapter 10 sounds more like an n-dimensional curved analogue of the right most integral, but I thought integrating functions was done by the Riemannian volume form? And that still leaves me wondering how to generalise the middle to get a "curved scalar hypersurface integral", of the kind you might see on the RHS of an $n$-dimensional divergence theorem, say. I think this needs a Riemannian metric, but am unsure how it could be used, since problem 4.3 rules out the existence of any differential form $\omega$ such that $\omega "=" ds$ generalises the concept of a line element.

I would appreciate any assistance in clearing up this huge error in my understanding.

Comment: In your second paragraph, I'm confused by your confusion :) What do you mean when you say "freedom to choose the manifold $M$"? We are given beforehand $3$ pieces of data. A manifold $M$, a curve $\gamma$ in $M$, and a $1$-form $\omega$ on $M$. Then, $\gamma^*\omega$ is a $1$-form on $[a,b]$, hence if you let $t$ denote the identity coordinate on $[a,b]$, then $\omega=f\, dt$ for some unique $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$. So, $\int_{\gamma}\omega:=\int_{[a,b]}\gamma^*\omega := \int_a^b f$, where the last integral is the standard Riemann-integral of a real function

Comment: What I am confused by is the contradiction between the "manifold approach" of "I should only care about my 1-D manifold $[a,b]$, so who cares what $M$ is or does", which makes sense since the point is everything should be intrinsic, and the "calculating stuff in practice approach" in that it sure as hell does matter what $M$ is or does since working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^{20}$ or a manifold valued curve feels like it makes a big difference when calculating pullbacks.

Comment: I guess what I am thinking is, the curve $\gamma(t)$ is a 1 dimensional manifold that exists regardless of how we choose to embed it in a plane or 3-d space (or something stranger), so why does this come up when in chapter 10 we quite rightfully don't encounter this problem at all (the data $M$ is not needed or provided, it's built in with the charts and the domain of integration and it's chosen to be the patch of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that $N$ is diffeomorphic to, if that makes sense)

Comment: The important point in the "manifold approach" to line integrals is the pullback $\gamma^*$. The one-form $\omega$ is originally defined on the ambient manifold $M$ and has to be pulled back to a one-form on $[a,b]$. Once we've done this, we can "forget about $M$", but how $\gamma$ maps into $M$ will influence what the pullback $\gamma^*\omega$ looks like.